# OpenApi Java code generation field capitalization

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm using org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask to generate Java code from my yml based openapi.

Is there a way to specify how the generated fields should be capitalized?
For example:

```
AIOBCategory:
 type: string
 maxLength: 100
 example: ASD1234
```

is generated as

```
@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_AI_O_B_CATEGORY)
private java.lang.String aiOBCategory;
```

Instead I would like to be generated as:

```
private java.lang.String AIOBCategory;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need change your configuration

https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/configuration

Gradle Plugin

```
openApiGenerate {
    generatorName = "mysql-schema"
    inputSpec = "$rootDir/spec.yaml".toString()
    outputDir = "$buildDir/mysql".toString()
    configOptions = [
            identifierNamingConvention: "snake_case"
    ]
}
```

You need change the `"snake_case"` to `"original"` to keep the same format